# Change textsize of Drawer item android

Tags: android, materialdrawer

Hi I am using this [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) and I want to change the text size of the drawer item.

There is no api method to change the text size as given in this [issue](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/510).

He has said to overwrite the `dimens.xml` and change like below in this [issue](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/397)

```
<!-- Override the default value 14sp if you want do it!-->
    <dimen name="material_drawer_item_primary_text">16sp</dimen>
```

I added this library to my project using build.gradle

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

And now unable to find the dimens.xml and change that text size.
How can I achieve it. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the text size in your app's dimens.xml

Add dimens.xml in res->values folder with
 `<dimen name="material_drawer_item_primary_text">16sp</dimen>` in it.

Comment: This however does not change the text size of the header view. Is there another dimen I need to specify?